# Unable to assign IP address to client using udhcpd

Tags: wireless, hotspot

I'm trying to setup my Raspberry Pi3 as a WiFi hotspot.  I've used three different sets of instructions after complete reloads and cannot get any of them to work.   I can see the RP3 in my list of WiFi networks and can connect.  However my tablet (Google Samsung ) does not get an IP assigned.

I don't know anything about the OS and thus don't have any idea on what to try to do to diagnose.

Additional Information

I loaded by Pi3 with the latest version of Raspian.  Like with the message above the Pi3 was not assigning an IP.

I noticed tonight that I could connect to the internet via direct connect/cat5 but not WiFi.

Yesterday I was on with WifI but could not get an IP address assigned to me tablet.  So i don't know what the issue is.   Here is what i have setup.

1. Installed hostapd udhcpd
2. Configure DHCP (`/etc/udhcpd.conf`)

[image]

3. Changed `/etc/default/udhcpd`.  `New line = #DHCPD_ENABLED="no"`
4. Ran `sudo ifconfig wlan0 192.168.42.1`
5. Added to the bottom of the file `/etc/network/interfaces`.  Instructions were if the line "iface wlan0 inet dhcp" is not present, then add these lines to the bottom of the file.
   This line was not present in my file so I added:
6. Was supposed to comment out (#) the following lines  in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

   ```
    allow-hotplug wlan0, 
    wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf, and 
    iface default inet manual.
   ```

   However I only changed the top line since it was the only one in my file (`#allow-hotplug wlan0`)
7. Configure  `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` 
   [image]
8. Changed  `/etc/default/hostapd  line #DAEMON_CONF=""` to  `DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"`
9. Ran `sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"`
10. Added the following line to the bottom of  `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

    ```
     net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
    ```
11. Ran the following commands in this order

    ```
    sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE 

    sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state      RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 

    sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT 

    sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat"
    ```
12. Changed  `/etc/network/interfaces` and added the following line to the bottom of the file:

    ```
    up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
    ```
13. Ran

    ```
    sudo service hostapd start 

    sudo service udhcpd start
    ```

At this point I could see the Wireless network but the Pi3 never assigned an IP to my tablet.  This was yesterday when the WiFi appeared to work.  Today the WiFi does not appear to be working

Ran this just to finish

```
sudo update-rc.d hostapd enable 
sudo update-rc.d udhcpd enable
```

Comment: We need more details, then we will be able to help

Comment: Welcome - but there are problems with questions that say, "I've tried a bunch of things.." but then do not say **in detail** what it is you've tried and **exactly** how it has gone wrong. Please read ["What does it matter that my question is “unclear” or “too broad”, etc?"](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/794/what-does-it-matter-that-my-question-is-unclear-or-too-broad-etc) (note the paragraph which begins, *"I don't have to explain the details of my problem because..."*), and take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand the site better.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of detail, I’m new to this and have really no programming experience, no excuse I know so I will do better.    I added additional details to.my original message above.

Comment: I understand and realize that rant is long winded -- part of the point is make the context clear to people new to technical forums.   Stack Exchange (of which we are a part) can be a great tool but may take some scrutiny ;)  I'm sorry this wasn't reopened sooner.  You might want to double check/look more closely at what's going on with the tablet; that something connects but does not have an IP is a bit nonsensical, because if it is successfully connecting to the internet *something* is routing traffic back and forth (which cannot happen unless it has an IP address).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an active DHCPD on your Raspberry? If you have you should take a look into the configuration with:

```
vi /etc/dhcp/dhpd.conf
```

If you don't have a dynamic range set your tablet won't get an IP address.

Does your WiFi hotspot work if you use a different device (maybe a laptop)? If it's possible you could try setting a static IP address to your device so you could see if there's just a problem with your DHCP.

Comment: Yes, I believe a dynamic range is set.   I added a screen shot (s) above and from what I understand the first sets the range.         I also tried to connect through both my tablet and phone neither of which would connect.  As of last night I could not connect throguh WiFi on my Pi3.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you have all the proper setup (from what I can see) that is needed for hostapd to be working. The issue is with the dhcp, by default the latest raspbian has dhcpcd installed on the OS. You will need to edit the file `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and add the following line `denyinterfaces wlan0` to the end. Afterwards, reboot and it should work properly. Another way to do this is :

```
sudo su
echo "denyinterfaces wlan0" >> /etc/dhcpcd.conf
reboot
```

Comment: Thanks.   I added and rebooted and still getting "no wireless interface found" when I hover over the WiFi/ Internet icon (I'm using Noobs)  somthing must be turning off the Wifi???   When I try to connect it just keeps.prompting for my password.

Comment: I've tried changing a couple of seting in /etc/network/interfaces to no avail.  Wifi will still not come on.      Any ideas.   I can add the file if needed.

Comment: The RPi3 can be seen on my mobile  devices but they still just search for an IP address never getting one asigned.     Rpi3 is not assigning an IP address.  Help?

Comment: @Peg unfortunately I used isc-dhcp-server. And this is what I did. https://bareinhard.github.io/2017/02/10/Setup-Car-Wifi-Raspberry-Pi-3-AP-No-Internet.html the important bits is what I did for the dhcp portion. I didn't add forwarding but my setup does hand out ips to connecting devices.

Comment: I'm going to relaod my card and at this point start over with these instructions.   He does say ios, I'm assuming this is not ios specific.    Is that true.

Comment: @Peg I wrote the article for a pi to be used as an audio receiver. The hostapd and dhcp server work well but I just didn't add the forwarding bit since it was meant as an Internet less setup. The iOS bit was in regards to streaming music via shairport-sync I believe adafruit had a nice tutorial for what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm trying  to set mine up as a wifi hot spot to connect to from my tablet without the Internet as it appears that you did.   Are you saying your instructions will not work?     I've tried using a pdf that I downloaded from adafruit and I could not get that to work either so I tried the one I had outlined above in my original post.  In fact the one above in my post is the third set that I've tried.     I unfortunately don't know a lot about this and just trying to get one to work.      Thanks for your help

Comment: @Peg mine works for giving out IP address and connecting. However I did not add the forwarding from the eth0 to wlan0. I believe I have some old favorited site that's will show this but give me about a day to track it down. from what I recall, it took a few hours of googling to get the one that worked.

Comment: Greatly appreciated.   I keep trying different ones and can't find one to work.

Comment: Thanks but I got it to work.  I found this doc specifically for Rpi3 and it worked.       https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/        on to the next step to try and stream video.

Comment: @Peg funny that's the link I was going to send. Glad it worked out for you. You should post it as an answer .

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the Hotspot setup using the info from the following site.  This was quite helpful and worked for me.

https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/